# I want to load alert and meantime want to load html link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

What i want is, when i press the button "accept your promotion" sweet alert pop up need to be popes up and same time link need to be called. that link is relevant for Boolean update to a data column in a database.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.0/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
     <form>
        <a href=\"http://localhost:8080/update/status/"+pcode+"/ACCEPT\"></a><input a href=\"http://localhost:8080/update/status/"+pcode+"/ACCEPT\" class="MyButton" onclick="myFunction()" type = "button" value ="Accept Your Promotion" />
    </form>

    <script>
function myFunction() {
       swal(
      'Congratulations!',
      'You successfully accept your promotion',
      'success'
    )
}
</script>
```

what would be the suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: Promotion? What are we talking about o.ô

Comment: well issue is you have a race condition. So only thing you really can do is catch the link click, cancel the event, show the modal, and use a timeout to follow the link.

Comment: How does an input have an href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to send some data back to the server AND display sweet alert once the user clicks to accept the promotion? If so you will be best to send the data back via Ajax. Take the href attribute away from the input, it’s not a valid attribute for an input. Make my function something like:

Native JavaScript

```
function myFunction() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "/update/status/" + pcode + "/ACCEPT/");
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      swal("Congratulations!", "You successfully accept your promotion");
    } else {
      swal("Uh oh, we failed to process your promotion.");
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

Or for JQuery...

```
function myFunction() {
  $.ajax("/update/status/" + pcode + "/ACCEPT/").then(
    function success() {
      swal("Congratulations!", "You successfully accept your promotion");
    },
    function fail(data, status) {
      swal("Uh oh, we failed to process your promotion.");
    }
  );
}
```

So when the button is clicked it will send a GET request to that URL which I’m assuming you’ve set up to mark the promotion as accepted in the database on the server. If the server responds to the get request with http status 200 success, then the alert will display congratulations... IF the GET request fails for any reason then it will alert the user of the failure.

Comment: Sir, Actually here i don`t want to send data into a server. what i want is when i press the button, display the sweet alert and open that link. when open that link it will call Spring Api so that some value will change in the database. i think JQuery ajax method need to be implemented here but i dont know how to do that

Comment: You can use jquery if you want but if your only using it to make ajax calls then your loading in a very large library when you dont need to.  Native javascript ajax is almost as simple as JQuerys IMO.  That said, if your using JQuery already then yes, use JQuery for sure.  Ill update the answer to include jquery aswell.  Also, if we just make a GET request via ajax then yes your not really sending any data.  The server will just see you made a request for that update/status url, and so will have the same effect as if you actually navigated to that address in your browser.